# Bootstrap DatePicker, how to set the start date as next day 12AM?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I was trying to make use of bootstrap date picker, and make the user to select next day or above in the calendar.

How to make the (data-date-start-date="12AM next day") instead of (data-date-start-date="+1d").

To be precise, the selected insurance policy needs be covered from next day 12AM.

I'm banging my head from last couple of days, tried most of the known probabilities.

It needs to be set via Bootstrap date picker! Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-start-view="0" data-date-force-parse="false" data-date-start-date="+1d"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1); //this will set tomorrow
            d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //this will set 12 AM
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                    defaultDate: d,
                });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the OP with some detail about why this will solve their issue?

Comment: @Azra, thanks for the code snippet that you provided. I was looking for something that can set 12 AM EST, using bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap-datepicker is not designed to be concerned with time ([search the documentation for the word "time"](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=time&check_keywords=yes&area=default)).

There are [other libraries](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) that help with picking dates *and* times.